# Angular5 reactive forms with mailcheck.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

below is HTML code for form

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>

     <input type="email" class="form-control" 
     (blur)="suggestEmail(signupForm.controls['userData'].controls.email.value)"
     id="email" formControlName="email">


     <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!signupForm.get('userData.email').valid && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched">
      please enter a valid email id 
     </span>
  </div>
```

Below is ts code

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      userData: this.fb.group({
        email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
      })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  suggestEmail(email) {
    Mailcheck.run({
      email: email,
      domains: ['gmail.com', 'aol.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'rediffmail.com', 'edu', 'msn.com',], 
      secondLevelDomains: ['domain', 'hotmail'], 
      topLevelDomains: ["com", "net", "org", "info"],
      suggested: function (suggestion) {
        console.log(suggestion);
        if (suggestion) {
          alert(suggestion.full);

         console.log(suggestion.full + "dkdjdekjekde")
        }
      },
      empty: function () {
      }
    });

  }
```

Right now, value of  `suggestions.full` comes in alert if its being called. But I am trying to show `suggestions.full` in html side, like as a error warning.

Below is link to my stackblitz
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid potential problems with access to `this` within the Mailcheck.run `suggested` callback, you could save the results of `Mailcheck.run`, check them and, if appropriate, set an error on your form field.

```
let check = Mailcheck.run({
   email: email,

   ... other stuff ...

   suggested: (suggestion) => {
     return suggestion;
   },
   empty: () => {
     return false; // or however you want to handle it...
   }

if (check && check.full) {
  this.suggestedEmail = check.full;
  this.signupForm.get('userData.email').setErrors({ 'has_suggestion': true })
}

// then in your template (using a getter)
<span class="help-block" 
      *ngIf="f.invalid && f.touched && f.errors?.has_suggestion">
  Suggestion: {{suggestedEmail}}
</span>
```

Please find this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-nyrqkj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) -- hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular `function` which will be lost `this` scope whereas `arrow` function keeps track of `this`. Read more about the difference here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/5836034

do something like this

```
....
suggestion: any;
....
suggestEmail(email) {
   Mailcheck.run({
      email: email,
      domains: ['gmail.com', 'aol.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'rediffmail.com', 'edu', 'msn.com',], 
      secondLevelDomains: ['domain', 'hotmail'], 
      topLevelDomains: ["com", "net", "org", "info"],
      suggested: (suggestion) => {
        console.log(suggestion);
        if (suggestion) {
          alert(suggestion.full);
         this.suggestion = suggestion; 
         console.log(suggestion.full + "dkdjdekjekde")
        }
      },
      empty: function () {
      }
    });
}
```

Observe the use of arrow function, to keep track of `this` scope and also, assigning the value of `suggestion` to your class variable via

> this.suggestion = suggestion

in your template, you can now have access to `suggestion` like so

```
<div *ngIf="suggestion">{{suggestion.full}} </div>
```

Source: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-checker-bjcrcc